# change the background of each individual elemente in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to change the background of defaul in a gridview for every single element .. does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random` to generate random color and set it as background like this :

```
Random random = new Random();
int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
```

it will generate an integer from 0 to 255.

If it's images you need to create an array with drawables and use `Random` with the size of the array -1 .